# Sync Apple Calendar & Google Calendar into native Calendar application

Tags: release-loki, calendar

I am a newcomer to elementary OS.

I am struggling with syncing Apple Calendar (iCal) in the elementary OS Calendar app. I tried to "make it public; copy URL and login with iCloud Login/pass" - but it keeps asking for iCloud credentials and doesn't sync.

The same issue happens with Google Calendar, with a personal Gmail account and with a Google Apps Enterprise account, both with 2FA enabled.

In the iCal issue, I really don't know what to do. Google Calendar wise, I didn't try to setup using "App Password" option, yet.
Thoughts?

I am using the latest eOS Loki's update.

Answer (score 9):

For Gmail:

1. Go to Go to https://myaccount.google.com/security
2. Click App passwords: [image]
3. Generate it and copy
4. In calendar app enter google email and generated password.

Answer (score 4):

There are some bugs for now, but I got it working with two-step authentication.

1. I cannot setup Google Calendars without installing Evolution. After my calendars got setup in Evolution, they did become visible in Maya (native calendar app) as well.
2. There is often an offset of one day for your daily appointements (https://bugs.launchpad.net/maya/+bug/1442188)

Sorry, no clues for Apple Calendar.

Answer (score 3):

I use 2-Step Verification for all my Google stuff. The way I got around this was to set an App password for Calendar. The option is under 2-Step Verification on the https://myaccount.google.com/security page.

Answer (score 2):

For Google you need to authorize "Less secure apps" here https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Once you turn that on you should be able to add your Google calendar.

Answer (score 0):

authorize less secure apps is not working for me.

I am using minetime a couple of days and this app is working fine for me with all my external calendars

Answer (score 0):

I hope its not to late.
On top right side, click menu - Add New Calendar, choose type GOOGLE

[image]

put your gmail on user fields, evently will show popup to insert password gmail - if you use two factor auth, dont put your gmail password, but generate App Password from Google here https://myaccount.google.com/security

[image]

Click App Password - generate password for your calendar app. Fill this password to popup window from calendar App.

I hope it works. Thanks